# ¿Como evitar mostrar los meses con venta en cero, es decir solo mostrar los que si tienen un valor diferente a cero?

Tags: mysql

Buenas tardes compañeros, tengo la siguiente consulta en mysql:

```
    SELECT FECHA, NOMALMACEN,
     IF(MONTH(FECHA) = 1,  TOTALVENTA, 0) AS Enero,
     IF(MONTH(FECHA) = 2,  TOTALVENTA, 0) AS Febrero,
     IF(MONTH(FECHA) = 3,  TOTALVENTA, 0) AS Marzo,
     IF(MONTH(FECHA) = 4,  TOTALVENTA, 0) AS Abril,
     IF(MONTH(FECHA) = 5,  TOTALVENTA, 0) AS Mayo,
     IF(MONTH(FECHA) = 6,  TOTALVENTA, 0) AS Junio,
     IF(MONTH(FECHA) = 7,  TOTALVENTA, 0) AS Julio,
     IF(MONTH(FECHA) = 8,  TOTALVENTA, 0) AS Agosto,
     IF(MONTH(FECHA) = 9,  TOTALVENTA, 0) AS Septiembre,
     IF(MONTH(FECHA) = 10, TOTALVENTA, 0) AS Octubre,
     IF(MONTH(FECHA) = 11, TOTALVENTA, 0) AS Noviembre,
     IF(MONTH(FECHA) = 12, TOTALVENTA, 0) AS Diciembre
  FROM registrodiario AS rd
  INNER JOIN almacen AS alm
  ON alm.CODALMACEN = rd.ALMACENID
  WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-08-31' AND ALMACENID = 1;
```

El agrupar por mes esta genial, pero me surge un interrogante: si yo estoy consultando en año actual, como haría para no mostrar los meses de septiembre a diciembre ya que estarían sin valor, ¿cómo los omitiría?
ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si miramos los meses que no hay registro salen en cero, en mi caso yo preferiría no mostrarlos, gracias de antemano si tienen la respuesta.

Comment: evitar columnas es algo muy complejo... porque querrias hacer esto en mysql, y no en la aplicacion que muestra la salida???

Comment: Hacer eso a nivel de SQL es complicado, pero a nivel de frontend no suele serlo. Mi sugerencia es que lo manejes en el front.

Comment: Es una convención. Por ejemplo puedes definir que los meses sin data sean nulos en vez de cero. En tu frontend obedeces la misma convención y no dibujas las columnas nulas. Pero esa convención la decides tú, y no es a nivel de consulta. La idea es no tener que modificar el SQL cuando llegue septiembre, no crees?

Comment: Claro tienes razón es eso, toca en C# hacer la validación

Comment: Hola, la Comunidad agradeceria que si alguna de las respuestas dadas en tu pregunta es correcta o te ayudo a solucionar tu problema, marques estas como respondida, adicional esto te dara resputacion como usuario y en tu cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tu requieres lo conozco como `dynamic pivot`, y tal como te comentaron es un lio.

En [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) esto se puede realizar creando una consulta como string y luego evaluándola.

Para tu caso particular me parece que para simplificar en algo el problema habría que crear una tabla adicional con los meses del año

```
create table meses(
  id int,
  nombre varchar(22)
);

insert into meses values
(1,"Enero"),
(2,"Febrero"),
(3,"Marzo"),
(4,"Abril"),
(5,"Mayo"),
(6,"Junio"),
(7,"Julio"),
(8,"Agosto"),
(9,"Septiembre"),
(10,"Octubre"),
(11,"Novimebre"),
(12,"Diciembre");
```

Y luego la consulta sería, algo como:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT( 
      CONCAT(
      'IF(MONTH(FECHA) = ''',
      id,
      ''', TOTALVENTA, 0) AS ',
      nombre
    ))
FROM meses
where id<=  MONTH('2023-08-31') into @sql;



SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM almacen
                  WHERE FECHA BETWEEN \'2023-01-01\' AND \'2023-08-31\'
                  ');

PREPARE consulta FROM @sql;
EXECUTE consulta;
```

Si te fijas bien la consulta tiene 2 partes:

- La primera es la formación del `select` pero concatenando los campos. Se realiza de forma dinámica gracias a la tabla `meses`
- La otra parte, es básicamente el resto de tu consulta, pero concatenándola con la primera parte

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rnkHg7Au5WNHphTUeimjKb/0)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Yussef, me parece interesante esta manera, voy a probarla y te cuento como me va, gracias

Comment: me funciono, pero al meterlo dentro de un procedimiento me genera error

Comment: me funcionas Yusset, pero al momento de llevarlo a un procedimiento almacenado, genera error